# Mule CE: Database Connector and JBoss/XA Transaction work together?

Tags: jboss, transactions, mule, mule-studio, spring-transactions

I would like to use JBoss/XA Transacion with Database Connector component in Mule 3.7.

But an exception is throws:  `Transactional action is ALWAYS_JOIN but there is no active transaction (java.lang.IllegalStateException)`.

My transactional scenario is:

1. Pool + Database component - `select` table A
2. VM Component. Just to start a transaction - `ALWAYS_BEGIN`
3. Database component - MySQL - `insert` table B
4. Database component - Oracle - `insert` table C

We must ensure that both inserts running and commit together or rollback together.

Following XML code:

```
<jbossts:transaction-manager doc:name="JBoss Transaction Manager">
  <property key="com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.defaultTimeout" value="50" />
  <property key="com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.txReaperTimeout" value="108000"/><
</jbossts:transaction-manager>
<spring:beans>
  <spring:bean id="oraDataSource" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolXADataSourceImpl" name="Bean">
     <spring:property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//${db.host}:${db.port}/${db.instance}"/>
     <spring:property name="user" value="${db.user}"/>
     <spring:property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
     <spring:property name="connectionFactoryClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource"/>
     <spring:property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
     <spring:property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
     <spring:property name="connectionWaitTimeout" value="30"/>
  </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>  

<spring:bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource">
    <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://${mysql.host}:${mysql.port}/${mysql.instance}?user=${mysql.user}&amp;password=${mysql.password}" />
</spring:bean>

<db:oracle-config name="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Oracle Configuration Bean" dataSource-ref="oraDataSource"/>
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="MySQL Configuration Bean" dataSource-ref="mysqlDataSource"/>

<vm:connector name="VM" validateConnections="true" doc:name="VM"/>

<flow name="propostaFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="1000"/>
        <watermark variable="carimboTempo" default-expression="2016-01-01 00:00:00" selector="MAX" selector-expression="#[payload.date_modified]"/>
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database Proposta">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select a.id, a.number, a.date_modified from table_a a where a.date_modified > #[flowVars.carimboTempo]]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    </poll>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each - Proposta">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="in" connector-ref="VM" doc:name="VM">
            <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="10000"/>
        </vm:outbound-endpoint>
        <enricher target="#[flowVars.resultadoInsert1]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
        <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" transactionalAction="ALWAYS_JOIN" doc:name="Database 1">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into table_b(ID, NAME) values(#[payload.id],#[payload.name])]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>
        </enricher>  
        <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" transactionalAction="ALWAYS_JOIN" doc:name="Database 2">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into table_c(ID, NAME) values(#[payload.id],#[payload.name])]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>
     </foreach>
</flow>
```

**IMPORTANT:** We are using `Mule 3.7.0 CE`. We know that in `Mule EE` a solution is very easy with `<transaction>` and `XA`.

Questions:

1. Did we something wrong?
2. Is the Database Connect component aware of the JBoss/XA Transaction?
3. Is a correct form to start XA transaction with VM Component?
4. Finally, what we want to do, embed XA transaction in Mule CE, is really possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I find something like this: http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/how-to-work-with-jdbc-and-xa-transactions/. But occur a error with this configuration. It´s should works in Mule CE 3.7?

Answer (score 0):

Based from the link you provided, since you use the driver classes oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource and com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource you need to update the configuration like the following:

```
<jdbc:inbound-endpoint queryKey="selectQuery"
    connector-ref="jdbcConnectorSource" pollingFrequency="10000">
    <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
</jdbc:inbound-endpoint>

<jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insert_call"
    connector-ref="jdbcConnectorDest">
    <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
</jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: JDBC Component in Mule 3.7 is deprecated. Unfortunately I didn´t find a solution to use in XA transaction Mule CE.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience I have found that the only way to use XA transactions is to use Mule EE.

You have to include your transactional operations (for example database update and JMS publishing ) in this block

```
<ee:xa-transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
```

and be sure to use database XA datasource, JMS XA connection factory and a transaction manager like this

```
<jbossts:transaction-manager  doc:name="JBoss Transaction Manager"  />
```

I've noticed this difference in Anypoint Studio between CE and EE.

In Mule CE transactional block, you can only specify transaction action

[image]

Instead in Mule EE you can specify transaction action **and** transaction type

[image]

Francesco.